(Stability)Let  be an -vertex triangle-free graph with at least ⌊^2/4⌋− edges.Prove that  can be made bipartite by removing at most  edges
This is a question from Yufei Zhao's book on graph theory Graph theory and Additive Combinatorics, Exercise 1.1.6
So I tried using H as a subgraph of G which is bipartite which would mean H has at least ⌊^2/4⌋−k-x edges as H=G-x and G has at least ⌊^2/4⌋ edges but then I need to prove that x=k but I don't know how to do that.
But perhaps my approach is wrong in itself.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

if $G$ is connected, then you can delete an edge and form a bipartite. Then the problem becomes estimating the number of connected components of G.

@Yimin No, there are plenty of connected triangle-free graphs that cannot be made bipartite by deleting a single edge.

@MishaLavrov thanks for correcting me, the "component" should be an edge and its neighbors.
